# libcurl Error: "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates"

Tags: c++, xcode, openssl, libcurl, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to connect to a FreeBSD server from Mac OS X (High Sierra) through HTTPS. We are using self-signed certificate. I am downloading the certificate using the command

```
/usr/bin/openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect 192.168.5.140:443
```

The code I am using to connect is

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, Serveraddress);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, request);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1L);

curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,"PEM");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO, <CertificatePath>);
```

The same code is working in another machine (OS X Yosemite). The only difference I could find is, when downloading the certificate using the above-mentioned command, I get these messages:

In the machine where the code is working:

```
 No client certificate CA names sent
 Peer signing digest: SHA512
 Server Temp Key: DH, 2048 bits
```

In the machine where code is not working:

```
No client certificate CA names sent
```

How to solve this issue? I tried specifying both Verify-Peer and Verify-Host as 0, it didn't work.

I tried the solution described [Here](https://medium.com/@timmykko/using-openssl-library-with-macos-sierra-7807cfd47892). It did not work.

Appreciate the help.